# ContentDialog is not displayed in the center

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

With "Show window contents while dragging" off. ContentDialog does not display correctly.

How to fix it?

[image: ContentDialog display issue]

Comment: It seems like a bug in the framework to me. Try submitting it in Feedback Hub.

Comment: I have sent a request to them. https://aka.ms/Dgt7ba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue on my side. My testing environment is `Windows 10 OS build 15063.540`, local machine. And my UWP app is also target build 15063. My testing sample is the [XamlUIBasics official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics).

So please upgrade your OS version to the newest to try to avoid the issue. It seems like even it is an issue it should be already fixed on the newest version.

Comment: Oh. I use `Windows 10 OS build 16281.1000 Insider Preview Fast Ring`

Answer (score 0):

You may subscribe to **Window.Current.SizeChanged** and layout your dialog manually like:

```
    private void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogPositionX = (e.Size.Width - YourDialog.ActualWidth) / 2;
        var dialogPositionY = (e.Size.Height - YourDialog.ActualHeight) / 2;
    }
```

You may apply new position to **Visual.Offset**, to **Margin** or **Canvas.SetLeft/Top**.

I don't know if it'll help but try also to call `UpdateLayout()`